# Differentiate equation with parenthesis

Tags: derivatives

I have a problem. I'm studying calculus, but I don't have a good math background, so I have a problem: I don't know well how to differentiate an equation with parenthesis.

The equation is the following:

$f(x) = 25x^3(x-1)^2$

Is it correct to use the Differentiation Product Rule in this way:

$f'(x)=75x^2*(x-1)^2+25x^3*2(x-1)$

or before I have to solve $(x-1)^2$ in this way:

f(x) = $25x^3*(x^2+1-2x)$ and then
     = $25x^5+25x^3-50x^4$

?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Its' the same.${}$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either way works. If you multiply out the products in your first result, you should discover that the two expressions you get for the derivative always have the same value.

Comment: While this is true for the example given, you really should point out that the chain rule needs to be used. I must say I'm really surprised not one of the answers mentions that.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they're both correct and equivalent. I'd use the first method and then factor out a $25x^2(x-1)$ to get $$f'(x) = 25x^2(x-1)\big(3(x-1) + 2x\big) = 25x^2(x-1)\big(5x - 3\big)$$

for the sake of neatness. If you multiply that out, you'll find that you get the same thing as expanding first and then differentiating term-wise.

Answer (score 2):

A small (useful) trick when you face products, quotients, powers,.. : logarithmic differentiation.

Let us take your cas $$f(x) = 25x^3(x-1)^2\implies \log(f(x))=\log(25)+3\log(x)+2\log(x-1)$$ Now, differentiate $$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\frac 3 x+\frac{2}{x-1}=\frac{5x-3}{x(x-1)}$$ $$f'(x)=f(x)\frac{5x-3}{x(x-1)}=25x^3(x-1)^2\frac{5x-3}{x(x-1)}=25x^2(x-1)(5x-3)$$

Comment: Hello there! Sorry but this is wrong; it is meaningless when $f(x) \le 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Just think of each sub-expression as a separate function, or possibly a composition of functions.  Then all derivatives can be resolved by application of the product and chain rules.

Example: Think of the sub-expression $x^3$ as the expanded product $x.x.x$.  Applying the product rule yields $x'.x.x + x.x'.x +x.x.x'$ = $1.x.x + x.1.x + x.x.1$ = ... *(repacking)* = $3x^2$.

Of course, once you hit $sin()$, $log()$, etc., you have to resort to something else.